# Getting pk from DetailView for lte/gte comparison (Django)

Tags: django, django-views

Goal: Implement next article / previous article feature on article page which is being served via DetailView. Compare current article pk against queryset in order to grab the next and previous articles.

I've tried a lot of different methods so far, but I'm getting errors on all of them.

```
class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        pk = Post.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
```

I've also tried:

```
pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
```

and

```
pk = self.kwargs['pk']
```

I get `KeyError` on the dictionary attempt and `None` on the get attempts.

I can't figure out why I'm not able to return the pk for the article in order to finish the code. Also, I've tried to get other data from the `Post` model, with the same errors.

edit:

URL's:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('cars/<slug:slug>', views.categories, name='categories_detail'),
    path('<slug:categories_detail>/<slug:slug>', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be seen from your url pattern that you are using the `slug` to get the correct `Post` object, and you never pass `pk` to the view. Instead you can get the `pk` from the object itself:

```
class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        pk = self.object.pk
        # Your code
        return context
```

Comment: Thanks @Abdul Aziz Barkat, this worked perfectly. For some reason I thought get() would retrieve the data despite not being passed into the view. I should probably go over the documentation again.